# Linux - turn off screen permanently

Tags: power-management, screen, monitor

I want to turn off the screen and keep it off even after a keyboard / mouse input.

- `xset dpms force off` does not do what I want.
- `vbetool dpms off` probably would, but it requires real mode and other funny stuff, which is why I can't get it to do anything but crash on a segfault.

It can be a third party utility or C / assembly / whatever other programmatic way.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Press the power button. If it's a laptop, use the bightness minus key.

Comment: I find that unplugging the monitor works well :P

Comment: @JacobVlijm I want to lock the computer and turn off the screen. After the correct password is entered, I want to turn the screen on. I am using [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock/) now, but I can only turn the screen off until a key is pressed; as soon as I begin typing the password, the screen turns on.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change backlight to zero and then restore it, although as @JacobVlijm pointed out, this only dims the screen instead of shutting it off.

```bsh
bl=`xbacklight`
slock xbacklight -time 0 =0
xbacklight -time 0 =$bl
```

Comment: Yeah, the issue isn't how to shut off the screen (can also be done with `xrandr --output` etc, but to trigger normal stat when unlocked again.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal stat"? I suppose there is something else besides the level of brightness, since that I've already taken care of. `slock` runs until the screen is unlocked, so after `slock` terminates, the brightness is restored (`$bl` is the original brightness level before setting it to zero). By the way, how would you do this using `xrandr`? I'm not very familiar with the tool.

Comment: with xrandr, you can actually shut off a screen, not just dimming. After log in, you'd need to switch it on again. not sure how to trigger that.

Comment: I don't know if this is generally applicable (I use Lubuntu) so posting as a comment - but in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` you can have a script called `session-setup-script` that runs at login to use `xrandr` to configure the displays. I have only used `display-setup-script` which configures the displays at boot, though.

Comment: I don't have `/etc/lightdm`, but then I'm on Fedora. I think the `session-setup-script` runs only on the first login (eg. after boot), not after you lock and unlock your computer. I tried to use `xrandr --off` and I had to hard-restart my PC because I couldn't turn the screen back on. Either way, I somewhat solved this problem using `xbacklight`. Turning the screen off completely would be nice though.

Comment: Fedora uses gdm, that's why you don't have it.